# Slice of slices types

Tags: types, go, slice

I'm currently working my way through the excellent [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/).
I finished one of the exercises (#45) with the following solution:

```
func Pic(dx, dy int) [][]uint8 {
    pic := make([][]uint8, dy) /* type declaration */
    for i := range pic {
        pic[i] = make([]uint8, dx) /* again the type? */
        for j := range pic[i] {
            pic[i][j] = uint8((i+j)/2)
        }
    }
    return pic
}
```

I don't understand why I have to use a `make` statement with the `uint8` type twice (see comments in snippet). That seems redundant but I can't figure out how to do it in an other way.

Comment: Arguably one could give a capacity of `dx*dy` to `pic` at the beginning with `pic := make([][]uint8, dy, dx*dy)` at the second line. Would that help performance, by allocating the required memory at once ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is no other way to do this in Go.

Yes, I agree it is verbose, but necessary. The second make() statement is entirely independent of the first one. It could be argued that the compiler should be able to infer the type from `pic[i]`, but it doesn't at this point.

Another point: how would the make() statement look if you omitted the type in the second case? The make() is still required to do the actual allocation and to be able to specify the required len/capacity.

As a side note, you mixed up the slice lengths. The exercise states the top level slice should have length `dy`, not `dx` as you put in your code.

Comment: About the side note. As I see in [exercise](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/18) it says "*It should return a slice of length dy, each element of which is a slice of dx 8-bit unsigned integers*". It means `dy` is the top level. I don't understand, did the author fix a code sample after your answer? Because it looks like your suggestion now is misleading. Sorry if I got something wrong. I'm also trying to understand this exercise now.

Answer (score 38):

To be explicit, we can use parentheses to rewrite `[][]uint8` as `[]([]uint8)`: a slice of (slices of type `uint8`).

Using the [make](http://golang.org/doc/go_spec.html#Making_slices_maps_and_channels) built-in function, for a slice of type `T`, `make(T, n)` returns a slice of type `T` with length `n` and capacity `n`.

Therefore, `make([][]uint8, 2)` is equivalent to `make([]([]uint8), 2)`, it returns a slice, with length and capacity of `2`, of slices of type `uint8`, where each slice of type `uint8` is initialized to its zero value (a `nil` reference with a length and capacity of zero).

Multi-dimensional slices are jagged and are analogous to multi-dimensional [jagged arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array).

For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ss := make([][]uint8, 2) // ss is []([]uint8)
    fmt.Printf("ss:    %T %v %d\n", ss, ss, len(ss))
    for i, s := range ss { // s is []uint8
        fmt.Printf("ss[%d]: %T %v %d\n", i, s, s, len(s))
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ss:    [][]uint8 [[] []] 2
ss[0]: []uint8 [] 0
ss[1]: []uint8 [] 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to jagged arrays!

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize slice of slices like that:

```golang
matrix2D := [][]int8{
    {1, 2, 3},
    {4, 5, 6},
}
fmt.Println(matrix2D) // [[1 2 3] [4 5 6]]
```